# Magento 2 email sender incorrect

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using magento 2.2.3 and hosted on magemojo hosting.Everything is working fine except email sender in emails.We any transactional email is sent sender email is not correct and it shows two emails i.e. of magemojo

Comment: If you can't get it to work, contact MageMojo support. They will fix it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Magento 2.2.4 or higher, either fresh or upgrade from 2.2.3, there is a bug that alters the email sender name.  It will change from your preset in the store configuration

> General -> Store Email Address

to the server usernames. Something like this:

2.2.3 – sales@example.com
2.2.4 – serverusername@myserver.magemojo.com or on Stratus this might be www-data@…mojostratus.io

A GitHub issue is tracking this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952 .  It is tested and confirmed the bug and a fix is to disable all the Amazon modules:

- Amazon_Core
- Amazon_Login
- Amazon_Payment

You can do this with the following commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Login
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Payment
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core
```

Then re-deploy production mode for your Magento 2 store.

Comment: What about the error : warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256 in C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 190  how to solve this @Andrew Smith

Comment: which version you are using as same error is not generated at my end ?

Comment: I am using 2.3, my frontend working good, back only the issue : Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256 in C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 190